# Creating a minimum working package in R--generic functions and other S4 objects (e.g., 'foo') cannot be dumped

Tags: r, object, module, package, r-s4

I was trying to create a minimum working package in R using the following command, however it failed. Are there better methods of creating a minimum working example of a package in R?

```
> package.skeleton("package") 
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Error in package.skeleton("package") : 
  generic functions and other S4 objects (e.g., 'foo') cannot be dumped; use the 'code_files' argument
```

Comment: Not "better", but worked for me and my 1st package: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PyQlbAEujY (= RStudio + {devtools} + {roxygen2})

Comment: @lukeA I very much liked it. Thank you!